# TOEFL IELTS GRE scores expired but with work experiences in English speaking countries

Tags: application, united-states, gre, toefl, ielts

If one wants to apply for grad school in the USA, and one's TOEFL, IELTS, GRE scores all expired, but one has all the following experiences able to prove ones' English proficiency:

one did an exchange student program in an English speaking country;
one has work experiences in English speaking countries;
one has published many papers in English.

Will these be sufficient reasons to persuade the admission office and pass their English requirements?

Comment: Only the individual programs can answer this question for you as far as the flexibility of their policies.

Comment: Go and get new scores - "hopefully" they will be better than the original ones...

Answer (score 0):

If a school requires test scores and they’re expired, you will likely be required to take the test again. Some schools may accept expired scores for evaluation purposes but will require valid scores to complete the matriculation process. In many US public schools, the TOEFL/IELTS scores are required to establish ability to work as an RA or TA, so having valid scores is necessary.

Comment: @ aeismail will the applicant b rejected for not having up to date english scores?